# Why is Facebook using react instead of more performant native JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, performance, dom

Please read this sequence on that [question (Update 5)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225400/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer) to understand the context :

> [React + Performance = ? article](https://aerotwist.com/blog/react-plus-performance-equals-what/) by Paul Lewis from July 2015 shows an
>   example where React is slower than vanilla JavaScript written by hand
>   for an infinite list of Flickr pictures, which is especially
>   significant on mobile. This example shows that everyone should always
>   test performance for specific use case and specific target platforms
>   and devices.

I am asking myself, why would Facebook use React to manipulate their DOM ?
It seems that manipulating DOM is faster with vanilla JS, which is kind of logical because React is written with JS.

**Isn't user experience much more important than developer ergonomics ?**

EDIT : For example Amazon found out that [100ms of latency cost them 1% of sales](https://blog.gigaspaces.com/amazon-found-every-100ms-of-latency-cost-them-1-in-sales/)

[image: Vanilla vs React DOM manipulation performance]

Comment: Lets holy war begin

Comment: @MysterX I don't think so. It's obvious when to pick vanilla or react.js

Comment: Perhaps the only people that *really* know why Facebook uses react, is Facebook. https://reactjs.org/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html

Comment: We should have sticked to writing assembly

Comment: In my experience I don't think Facebook really cares about performance above features.... and data of course.

Comment: Isn't Facebook then loosing users with low-latency (e.g. Africa) when the page is loading too long ?

Comment: _“Isn't user experience much more important than developer ergonomics ?”_ - do you have any proof or at least indication that this actually slows things down to a level where the user would notice? (Specifically for Facebook, I mean, not any arbitrary nice little examples someone on the web set up to prove a point.) Because otherwise this whole discussion is rather moot to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Read [Why Facebook Lite](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1365439333482197/how-we-built-facebook-lite-for-every-android-phone-and-network/) paragraph about 1.6 bilion people living with 2G networks.
Moreover I think like [Amazon](https://blog.gigaspaces.com/amazon-found-every-100ms-of-latency-cost-them-1-in-sales/), every even small speed performance is worth money.

Comment: So what, that still doesn’t prove that those people see/experience any effect of this.

Comment: You're right, I am just deducing that when seeing [low-latency countries](https://www.fastmetrics.com/internet-connection-speed-by-country.php) and that a facebook website is relatively heavy (6MB in my case) I'm thinking about speed performance. I would need to ask Facebook personally :p

Answer (score 4):

User experience doesn't matter here. React.js is about easiness to organize  UI in the fast manner.

React.js brings these values:

- Cross-browser code (vanilla JS doesn't have enough abstraction like Synthetic events)
- 10x times easier to write code for specific functions like a chat
- 100x times easier to maintain it. There is just one way to do something - so it's multiple times easier to understand business logic behind something big

Comment: Facebook states that they maintain 50000 React components.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings proof, please?

Comment: @asiniy [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/4edsvi/does_facebook_use_react_on_facebookcom/) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Facebook-app-built-with-react-js)

Comment: Read last paragraph in [ReactJS Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#gradual-migration-path)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings huge thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Well-structured Vanilla JavaScript will always be faster than React, although some extensions on React,have shown that frameworks can get damned close to VanillaJS when it comes to rendering speed.

The primary advantage of React is that it takes the task of structuring the JavaScript out of your hands. This allows for easier-to-understand code for other developers who are also versed in React, and it also allows rapid refactoring of well-structured React classes to accommodate new features. React gives you these powers while not suffering a huge hit to performance

Comment: Yeah I completely understand your point, that's why I am using React also over plain JS. But talking about a big company like Facebook, which is also targeting people with low-latency internet speed, performance is in my opinion crucial.
[Amazon is thinking about it.](https://blog.gigaspaces.com/amazon-found-every-100ms-of-latency-cost-them-1-in-sales/)

Maybe that's why [Facebook Lite](https://www.facebook.com/lite/) exists ?

Comment: @luiswill I think been able to maintain the code is really important and worth sacrificing a bit of performance to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Updating DOM is usually the bottleneck when it comes to the web performance. React is trying to solve this problem by using something called virtual DOM; a DOM kept in memory. Any view changes are first reflected to virtual DOM, then an efficient diff algorithm compares the previous and current states of the virtual DOM and calculates the best way (minimum amount of updates needed) to apply these changes. Finally those updates are applied to the DOM to ensure minimum read/write time. This is the main reason behind React’s high performance.

Comment: Yes I understand, but this [article](https://aerotwist.com/blog/react-plus-performance-equals-what/) points out that manipulating DOM with vanilla JS is faster (which is logical). So are Facebook Developers just using React for easiness ?